# What are the first steps in exploring Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, module, development

I am planning to start out with Magento 2.
Could you  please advise me on the first steps of transition from Magento 1 to Magento 2? I have quite little experience with Magento 1 development, but judging by M2 code, everything seems to be drastically changed. Can you suggest me to study any trusted, relevant resources?

Also, I would like to know how the basic principles have been changed, I mean: catalog, products, quotes, carts. If someone can share the experience of migrating from M1 to M2 ( the popular issues and their solutions) it will be very useful and I will be highly grateful.

P.S. I have already installed M2 and it has not caused any issues. I am highly interested in the extensions development and customizations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to what Steve Johnson has written, I would add the following source..

First and foremost, I recommend you to read this eBook, it's like the Bible for all beginning Magento 2 developers:

https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/magento-2-developers-guide

Also, check these best Magento 2 blogs - here you'll learn about some aspects of Magento 2 development, that the official Magento documentation doesn't mention:

- https://firebearstudio.com/blog/category/magento-2
- http://inchoo.net/category/magento-2/
- http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2
- http://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2

Also, you can find some useful info on Magento 2 in the official Magento blog:

- https://magento.com/blog/tag/magento-2

> Also, I would like to know how the basic principles have been changed, I mean: catalog, products, quotes, carts. If someone can share the experience of migrating from M1 to M2 ( the popular issues and their solutions) it will be very useful and I will be highly grateful.

Check this blog post to learn the basic differences between Magento 1 and Magento 2:

http://blog.litextension.com/whats-difference-between-magento-1-x-and-2-0/

Also, check out for the updates on our blog:

http://blog.mageworx.com/

we are about to launch the series of articles about the peculiarities of the main Magento 2 aspects and how the differ from Magento 1.

So, stay tuned!

Answer (score 2):

- [Getting Start Guide](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/getting-started.html?_ga=1.120700616.1995384089.1459000054)
- [Developing extensions](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/bk-extension-dev-guide.html)
- [Coding guidelines](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/coding-standards/bk-coding-standards.html)
- [Magento 1 to Magento 2 migration guide](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/migration/bk-migration-guide.html)
- [Front end development](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/bk-frontend-dev-guide.html)

Please let us know if this is the kind of information you're looking for.