# Magento 2 - How to list websites on frontend

Tags: magento2, websites

What's the best method to get specific data in Magento 2, i.e. to list all the websites in the CMS? In Magento 1 I'd use

```
Mage::app()->getWebsites()
```

But that doesn't work in Mag2 anymore. I do see code like this:

```
$this->storeManager = $storeManager;
$id = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
```

Which I guess would be a fair starting point, but whenever I call this code in the frontend, I get *Notice: Undefined variable: storeManager* errors. So appareantly this isn't the way to call that storeManager. My question is; what *is* the right way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get the list of all websites, you indeed need to use the `storeManager`, which is a native variable of every block extending `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template`:

In your block class, you either directly do:

```
$this->_storeManager->getWebsites();
```

Or if you need to get the websites in a template assigned to your block you can declare a function:

```
public function getWebsites() {
    return $this->_storeManager->getWebsites();
}
```

Then in your template you can do:

```
$block->getWebsites();
```

Note that if you want to get the websites in a controller or any other non block class, you will have to use dependency injection in the constructor first to be able to use the `storeManager` code above:

```
protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager)
{
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
}
```

Comment: Bear with me here, so I need to make a custom module to use that storeManager var, just to list the websites in the frontend? Seems rather extensive.

Comment: When you say "list the websites in the frontend" what does that mean ? In a template ? On a CMS page ?

Comment: I'm but a humble frontend developer, and Mag2 is quite new to me. All I want to do is to add a website switcher to the header, next to the language switcher. In Mag1 I'd just call the info using the Mage::app(); function. I guess what I'm looking for is the right workflow to get data like that in Magento2

Comment: Well there's already a store switcher provided with M2: `Magento\Store\Block\Switcher` with its corresponding template: `Magento\Store\view\frontend\templates\switch\stores.phtml`

Comment: I figured there would be, thanks. It doesn't do what I'd hope though (well, it does nothing), and seems to be checking `if (count($block->getGroups())>1): ` which returns false. But that's another issue I guess.
As for your original answer, do you have a good source as an introduction to using block classes, declaring functions like that? I want to learn, but the documentation is very scattered and unclear.

Comment: Well that's a whole another question to your OP, but I reckon you should keep an eye here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108851/what-are-the-first-steps-in-exploring-magento-2

Comment: Well, learn by doing :) Thanks for the quick answers. I'll take all these leads and start puzzling.