# count($block->getWebsites()) returns zero

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to change the **language switcher**(languages.phtml) to a **website switcher**.

```
echo count($block->getStores())
```

Returns the number of stores correctly but when I do

```
echo count($block->getWebsites())
```

it returns zero when I have 3 websites set up.
Is this code wrong or is there something that I need to look into?

Answer (score 1):

This link can be helpful for you. Haven't tried the code yet but it should be working:-

[Magento 2 - How to list websites on frontend](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109292/magento-2-how-to-list-websites-on-frontend)

In your **block** file:-

```
public function getWebsites() {
    return $this->_storeManager->getWebsites();
}
```

And then in your **template** file, you can check:-

```
count($block->getWebsites());
```

I am assuming you have not used this function in your block file, as it is not mentioned.

> P.S:- The link also have a discussion regarding Store switcher in
> comments, that can be helpful for you too.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the information. I really appreciate it. I didn't know about the block file thing, I will look into this!