# Is it necessary to learn Magento 1 for starting with Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

I am new to magento.

I want learn magento.

What should be my first step.

Should I start with magento 2.

Where I can find material for it.

Or is it necessary to **learn magento 1, before starting with Magento 2**?

Comment: Some useful information about the Magento 2 learning resources you can find [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108851/what-are-the-first-steps-in-exploring-magento-2), [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/52753/can-anyone-suggest-more-technical-resources-for-magento-2/79973#79973) and [here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112615/0-magento2-no-experience/112642#112642). I'll recommend you to start from the learning of Magento 2.

Answer (score 11):

Well I'm just going to give you my point of view based on my experience.

I've worked with Magento 1 for 5 years before starting developing on Magento 2.

To me, Magento 2 would be definitely **slightly** easier to learn if you have a bit of knowledge with Magento 1.

However, **Magento 2 introduces a lot of new concepts that were not present in Magento 1** and that I found a little bit disturbing at first sight because I was not used to them.

My advice would still be to **learn Magento 2 without learning Magento 1 as your mind won't be disturbed by Magento 1 concepts.**

Regarding good learning materials I highly recommend the **[Magento U Fundamentals course](https://magento.com/training/catalog/fundamentals-of-magento-2-development)** that I took myself and helped me a lot understanding the software.

On top of that I recommend the **[Alan Storm articles](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2)** that explain with deep investigations the concepts of Magento 2.

Also, **[Magento 2 dev docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/)** is a great place to start getting familiar with the software and how it works.

Try to get your hands on one of those books, it'll help you as well

[image]

Finally I suggest you use **Magento StackExchange and [Magento Forums](https://community.magento.com/)** as much as possible as you will get a lot of help from the community if you face any issue.

Comment: Being unbiased which one of them will you recommend? ;)

Comment: @MagePsycho honestly they are all very similar but as the Magento 2 Cookbook was featured during Imagine 2016 I reckon I will go for this one if I had to pick one