# learning approach for a Magento beginner

Tags: magento2, best-practice, learn-magento

I am new to magento. Before the question, my background:

1. I have some previous experience in php. I have developed a small e-commerce site for food ordering as part of my course project. (but I have used procedural method for the same)
2. I know the fundamentals of OOPS concepts. I have programming experience in c++ and java.
3. I know html5, css3 and js and have done some projects in them too.
4. I installed magento CE 2.1 in ubuntu 15.10 LAMP. I am using the Magento_Community_Edition_2.0_User_Guide to learn the basics.

I want to learn magento from 2 perspectives:

a. website owner

b. developer

i.e. I need to be able to setup an online store, run it and make customization in the front end and in functionality.

My questions:

A. Is an in-depth understanding of php OOPS and development experience required for this? Do you suggest learning this before looking at learning 
magento from a developer's perspective?

B. To learn magento from a store owner's perspective what leaning resources are available and what approach is suitable?

C. To learn magento from a developer's perspective what leaning resources are available and what approach is suitable?

D. Do I have to study about the previous versions of magento(1.x)?

If I have missed any core subjects please edit this question or include them in your answer.

Comment: That could answer some of your questions: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116381/is-it-necessary-to-learn-magento-1-for-starting-with-magento-2/116383#116383

Answer (score 3):

First thing, to learn Magento 2.x you don't need to learn magento 1.x.

To learn Magento 2.x, some of the best places are:

- [Magento's official website](http://devdocs.magento.com) (here you can find content for all)
- [Ashsmith blog](https://www.ashsmith.io)

Apart from these, have an eye at [Magento2 stack exchange](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento2)

Some more helpful links are:
http://alanstorm.com/category/magento-2

http://mageclass.com/magento2-tutorials/

http://inchoo.net/category/magento-2/

http://www.sessiondigital.com/blog/category/magento-2/