# it's necessary to learn Magento 1 for starting with Magento 2?

Tags: learn-magento

Is it necessary to learn Magento 1 for starting with Magento 2? and what are resources can i learn magento from it?

Comment: person having m1 knowlegde..definetly has a way too less learnin curve for m2..but if you are just starting out..no need to go back to older ways..the only advantage is..if online some blogs, docs are missing for m2, you canread up m1 and co-relate it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it necessary to learn Magento 1 for starting with Magento 2?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116381/is-it-necessary-to-learn-magento-1-for-starting-with-magento-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to learn Magento 1 as most things have changed between 1 and 2.  Right now one of the best places is to go through the lessons on Magento U.  Some other good blog posts are those from Alan Storm http://alanstorm.com/, Vinai Kopp http://vinaikopp.com/blog/list/.  You could also look at the Devdocs.magento.com to help get started.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary, but it helps. In addiction to the blog recommended by Brett (very good resources indeed) i suggest the Inchoo blog http://inchoo.net/category/magento-2/ (pretty simple) and the Alan kent blog https://alankent.me/category/magento/ for insights. Personally, I learn a lot by reading this forum. Good luck!